# "+" sign in JS mailto links (Android & Chrome)

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, urlencode, mailto

my web page which has a button that opens the email client with an email message.
When the user clicks the button, the following script is being executed (JavaScript).

My problem is that on Android 4.4.4 and Chrome 38, the mail client (Gmail or android's default) replaces the %20 in '+' sign.
I tried to `encodeUri`, `encodeUriComponent` and regular spaces chars but every time I get the '+' sign.
Any idea how to remove the '+' sign for regular space chars?

```
var addresses = "";
var subject = "";
var body
try {
    subject = config['email']['subject']  ;
} catch (e) {
    subject = "I%20think%20you%20will%20like%20it";
}

try {
    body = config['email']['body'];
} catch (e) {
    body = "Visit%20this%20link:";
}
body += document.URL;
var href = "mailto:" + addresses + "?"
     + "subject=" + (subject) + "&"
     + "body=" + (body);
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = href;
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
```

Answer (score 2):

Same here, but it's documented at various places:

[Android Board](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63538)

[Chromium Board](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=425657)